# PhpStorm phpspec code sniffer ignore test folder

Tags: php, phpstorm

I see warnings in my test classes when I try create it. I don't want create PHPDoc and more for tests classes, but PhpStorm shows me warnings, because PhpStorm cannot marked tests classes as exclude for phpcs.

How I run my phpcs for validate my classes for coding standards:

```
php bin/phpcs ./src -p --encoding=utf-8 --extensions=php --ignore=Tests --standard=./vendor/escapestudios/symfony2-coding-standard/Symfony2
```

How implement it for PhpStorm 2016.3.2?
I try create configuration:

```
<target name="phpcs-ci"
        description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer creating a log file for the continuous integration server">
    <exec executable="phpcs" output="/dev/null">
        <arg value="--encoding=utf-8" />
        <arg value="--extensions=php" />
        <arg value="--ignore=Tests" />
        <arg value="--standard=./vendor/escapestudios/symfony2-coding-standard/Symfony2" />
        <arg path="${basedir}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

And import this configuration in PhpStorm:
[image]

But my tests show me warnings again:
[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you need here. As I understand it so far you wish to disable Code Sniffer (PhpStorm integration) for your test files (for whatever the reason -- it does not matter) but still keep running it for your other code. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | Scopes`

Go there and create a [custom Scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/scopes.html) that would include such unwanted files/folders (the simplest way -- navigate to your `Tests` folder in the tree there and click on `Include recursively` button).

**NOTE:** In theory this step can be skipped if you mark your folders with tests as *"Test Source Roots"* (right-click in the Project View panel and choose the right type from `Mark Directory As` submenu; the same can be done via `Settings/Preferences | Directories`).

This way you could use the built-in "Tests" scope.

2. Save changes (either `Apply` ... or use `OK` and re-open Settings/Preferences screen again)
3. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`
4. Find `PHP | PHP Code Sniffer validation` inspection
5. Create a new rule for that recently created Scope.

Click on `In All Scopes` button (it's a button when only 1 rule is defined) and choose that scope.

[image]

6. Now just disable this inspection for that scope.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/changing-the-order-of-scopes.html